# 'Show' action with Angular and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to list the contents of a post using Angular with Rails, but totally stuck.

My controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

myApp.controller('categoryController', ['$scope', 'Post',function($scope, Post) {
    $scope.heading = "Hello from angular";
    $scope.post = Post.query(); 
}])

myApp.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/posts/:id', { id: "@id" } );
}])
```

Rails posts controller:

```
 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

'Hello from angular' is showing up fine, however the rest gives me an error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts/show 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Can't figure out the correct way to route this bad boy.
Thank you for any helpful input

Edit: routes.rb

```
  resources :users

  resources :hubs, shallow: true do
    resources :posts, shallow: true
    resources :comments, shallow: true do
      collection {post :sort}
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `routes.rb`?

Comment: @zeantsoi sure thing! updated

Answer (score 1):

The error you are showing is a 500, not a 404. I don't think this is a routing issue as much as it looks to be that something in your code is raising an unhandled exception.

I'm also a little confused because calling Post.query() should be making a query that routes to your index method, not your show method.

If you are trying to route to a show method you might want to do Post.get({id: someID}), otherwise what does your index method look like?

Comment: well I don't have an index method. I was just experimenting with Angular, and was trying to show only separate show methods.

Comment: @DenisG Did you try changing your Post.query() to a call to get() passing in some ID?

Answer (score 0):

The `query()` method sends a `GET` request without passing the Post id. That's why your URL is incomplete and you get a 500 error.

Define your factory like it's done in [this article](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-ruby-on-rails/consuming-rest-apis.html) and then call

```
$scope.post = Post.show(id);
```